# Display the dropdown and icon on the same line

Tags: html, css, angular, drop-down-menu, icons

I am trying to place the dropdown and the icon on the same line. But the icon is getting displayed on the next line

```
<div *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formGroup">
<div>
<formfield label="dropdown">
<dropdown>
 ------
</dropdown>
</-formfield>

<app-popover *ngIf="popup" [Popup]="popup"></app-popover>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: this is the current behaviour]

Comment: use css `display:inline-block` or put the icon inside `i` or `label` not `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dig into CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/display

For you: Just add the attribute `style="display: inline-block;"` to your HTML tag and it should work fine.